# how send infomation latitude and longitude to server a continuous

Tags: android, gps

My app got infomation latitude and longitude my location. Now,i want send this infomation to server a continuous every 5 minutes.but i don't have to do.Can you help me!!(i think should use service run background!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at TimerTasks they were made just for you 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Answer (score 0):

For a regular time interval based execution there are two classes available

- [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
- [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Both of these are made for repeative execution on certain interval, however AlarmManager uses lesser Battery. AlarmManager can also trigger the action even if the device is in the sleep mode or lock mode ( except some HTC devices who doesnt support during lock/sleep mode )